# how to get var value which with a var in name using jinja2

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I am using *ansible* to template a jinja2 file.

```
IP:{{ ansible_eth0.ipv4.address }}
IP:{{ ansible_docker0.ipv4.address }}
IP:{{ ansible_{{ ka_interface }}.ipv4.address }}
```

there is a var named ka_interface for network adapter.

but you will get error in 3rd var
`(IP:{{ ansible_{{ ka_interface }}.ipv4.address }} )`

It seems that var in jinja2 template can be  nested.

Comment: fatal: [k8sprod5 -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "AnsibleError: template error while templating string: expected token'end of print statement', got '{'. String: subjectAltName = DNS:{{ inventory_hostname }},DNS:{{ ansible_nodename }},DNS:kubernetes,DNS:kubernetes.default,DNS:kubernetes.default.svc, DNS:kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local, IP:10.96.0.1,IP:{{ k8s_api_vip }},IP:{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}\nIP:{{ ansible_eth0.ipv4.address }}\nIP:{{ ansible_docker0.ipv4.address }}\n{{ ansible_{{ ka_interface }}.ipv4.address }}\n\n"}

Comment: Please paste the code as text into your question then highlight and press Ctrl+K this allows us to copy and paste your code into our IDEs and help identify the problem. Please read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to know what code you need to include

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to construct a dynamic variable with Jinja2 syntax.

However, you can access any play-bound variables via the builit-in `vars` hash object:

```
{{ vars['ansible_' + ka_interface]['ipv4']['address] }}
```

**Edit**: Fixed hash syntax

Comment: - name: test1
  shell: echo {{ ansible_eth0.ipv4.address }}
  tags: test

- name: test2
  shell: echo {{ vars['ansible_' + ka_interface + '.ipv4.address'] }}
  tags: test

Comment: fatal: [k8sprod4]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute u'ansible_eth0.ipv4.address'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/usr/local/lvzj/github/ansible-kubeadm/roles/glusterfs/tasks/main.yml': line 48, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: test2\n  ^ here\n"}

Comment: Sorry I didn't aware of the incorrect syntax. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

follow Chris Lam 's advice,
It works

`- name: test
  shell: echo {{ vars['ansible_' + ka_interface]['ipv4']['address'] }}
  tags: test`

Comment: Instead of duplicating the answer, mark Chris' solution as "accepted" (checkmark next to the answer)